# What is the conditional order for checking if two pairs of things are true?

Tags: logical-or, logical-and

I have two parameters, a and b. There are two possible sets of values that if both of them is not true, I want to raise a warning. For example, I might want to raise a warning if both a=1 and b=1 is not true AND if both a=2 and b=2 is not true, but if one of the conditions (e.g. a=1 and b=1) is true I don't want to raise the warning. I'm not sure how to get the logic correct for this - I have tried

```
if not a == 1 and b == 1 or a == 2 and b == 2:
 #some warning
```

but this doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: draw a truth table

Answer (score 0):

you should put brackets on your condition to be like this:
if not (a==1 and b==1) or (a==2 and bee2)
#some warning
I suggest changing the logic to this:
if (a!=1 and b!=1) or (a==2 and b==2) instead.
I also recommended learning about de morgan laws from here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws
and calculate truth table for your conditions.